# Form Processing - Detection of Boxes to Separate Sections

Tags: python, opencv

I am developing a desktop application that will take a handwritten form (example of one is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpYT4.jpg)), read the numbers from it, and feed them into a csv file.

I am using a template matching algorithm to locate each header and return the coordinates, then I use those coordinates to chop out the relevant blocks along the y-axis so my program can read it later. The problem I'm having is how to tell the algorithm when to stop cropping.

Where I need help: I've designed the forms to have black boxes around each section. The theory is that after the template has been located on the form, I'll have a function that receives the coordinates of where the template was found (i.e. the 'Date' column is at 255,322,465,462), then locate the closest bottom-most corner (black box) to that section and return the coordinates.

I'm really new to image processing and its jargon so I'd love some advice as to how to execute this theory, such as opencv functions that might assist with the process, examples of similar projects, what terms I might need to google for more information (is there a specific name for this type of image processing?), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Connected Components feature in Opencv python, where you will get each individual boxes, later you can filter out boxes that you need.
Below is the sample code

```
img = cv2.imread('form.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)
```

you can specify a parameter connectivity to check for 4- or 8-way (default) connectivity. The difference is that 4-way connectivity just checks the top, bottom, left, and right pixels and sees if they connect; 8-way checks if any of the eight neighboring pixels connect

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't mark your response as the answer because I'm still a new user, but I was able to solve my issue.

Comment: Glad it helped! Also added information about connectivity parameter, it might help you to improve the result.